# How do I get a sum of the occurrence of each item in an array across all documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to get an aggregation/count of the occurrence of all items in an array across all documents. I've tried looking up examples but none of them seem to cover this scenario exactly or go about it in a very obtuse way.

Here's a simple idea of the document model i'm working with. The `itemIds` array within each object is always unique (no repeated values):

```
[{
    _id:1,
    itemIds:[3, 4, 6, 12]
},
{
    _id:2,
    itemIds:[4, 12]
},
{
    _id:3,
    itemIds:[3, 4, 8, 9, 12]
}]
```

I need the counts of each of these summed up (doesn't have to be this exact format but just giving a general idea of what I need):

```
{
    itemsCount:[
        {
           itemId:3,
           count:2
        },
        {
           itemId:4,
           count:3
        },
        {
           itemId:6,
           count:1
        },
        {
           itemId:8,
           count:1
        },
        {
           itemId:9,
           count:1
        },
        {
           itemId:12,
           count:3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Give some more info. Are those arrays always consist of unique numbers?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
    db.yourCollection.aggregate([
{$project : {'itemIds' : 1, _id :0}},
{$unwind : '$itemIds'}, 
{$group : {'_id': '$itemIds', count :{$sum :1}}}
])
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. You're changing the structure of the documents. The `itemIds` array is a root level item of the model i'm accessing. I tried that query and it didn't work.

Comment: @Brett84c : Ok you could just do unwind on itemIds and group on itemIds, then you would get the required output, let me update my answer !!

Comment: This worked! I really need to spend a couple days trying to understand Mongo aggregation but this certainly helps get the ball rolling for me on the project i'm currently working on and helps me understand aggregation a little better on a base-level. Thank you!

Comment: @Brett84c : check this if you wanted to learn mongo : https://university.mongodb.com/courses/catalog , these are free & directly from mongoDB, best way/place to learn..

Comment: I will definitely check it out. Thank you. Wish StackOverflow allowed you to tip people. I'd love to buy you a beer.